# Django display image on RadioSelect or Checkboxes

Tags: django, image, forms

I am new to django and I am trying to display pictures from a database onto a radiobutton or checkbox. How do I do that?

I have this model

```
class MyItems(models.Model):
itemName=models.CharField(max_length=100)
itemDesc=models.CharField(max_length=400)
itemImage=models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures')

class categories(models.Model):
catName=models.CharField(max_length=100)
items=models.ManyToManyField(MyItems)
```

Users uploads pictures to a page, and they can categories them into categories.

I could do this to make it show my choices

```
class catForm(forms.Form):
catName=forms.CharField()
items=forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect,choices=(MyItems.objects.all())
```

but how do I put something like this img tag into the label?

```
<img src="itemImage.url" />
```

Went through many tutorials but none of them generates images from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ModelForm` with a bit of customaization:

First sub class the `ModelChoiceField`

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class CustomChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return mark_safe("<img src='%s'/>" % obj.itemImage.url)
```

Now:

```
class CatForm(forms.ModelForm):
  items = CustomChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset=MyItems.objects.all())

  class Meta:
     model = categories
```

now use this form instead of your `catForm`. If you haven't used `ModelForm` before please see the django documentation for details on this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 
I tried it and it was able to change the label according to the database items. 
However, the image wont appear, only thing that appeared on the label were these instead of pictures
<img src='media/pictures/picture1.jpg">

Comment: do you see this text instead of image? btw, you need to append your host before the path, e.g. try returning `return "<img src='http://localhost:8000/%s'/>" % obj.itemImage.url`

Comment: I tried added localhost:8000 to it but it still returns text instead of images.

Comment: please see the updated answer, you've to mark the html as safe. now it should work

Comment: Yes it works!! THANKS A LOT, really appreciate your help.
Btw, 
is there any good reference sites you would recommend for these and more advance django stuffs?

Comment: you're welcome! I don't know about any reference sites. But you can search for django blogs, many people write regularly. I knew the solution because I faced similar problem before.